# Echo "$$" as text

Tags: bash, shell, unix

How I can print `$$` as text. For example script:

```
PASS="Pa$$w0Rd"
echo $PASS
```

This structure show me `Pa12515w0Rd` where `12515` it's current PID but I need to see `Pa$$w0Rd`.

Thanks in advance.

For more detail:

```
echo "Enter password:" #pass will be - Pa$$w0Rd
read PASS
echo $PASS
```

Comment: `PASS="Pa$$w0rd"` --> `PASS='Pa$$w0rd'`

Comment: I don't need to replace main variable. How it can be done with echo or printf ?

Comment: if you just want to display that string, then `echo Pa\$\$w0rd` will do.

Comment: Please read my question again. I have constant variable and I need to `echo` it to console with the same structure.

Comment: I don't see any problem in your updated question: the `$$` won't be expanded.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add an escape char 
like that :

```
$var = "PA\$\$ss";
echo $var;
```

Displaying `Pa$$w0rd` with  `echo` can be achieved with:

```
echo Pa\$\$w0rd
```

Comment: I don't need to replace main variable. How it can be done with `echo` or `printf` ?

Comment: And your code will lead to error. Please think before make an answer.

Comment: what ? It works well on my server. Somebody edit my code too, without quote